# Magento 1.6 - Invoice Emails are not being sent

Tags: paypal, magento-1.6

I have `Magento 1.6.0.0` and I use `Paypal Express Checkout`. The issue is that Invoice emails are not automatically sent. It says at the invoice details page:

> the invoice email is not sent

Can someone tell me whats the issue here?

The Order confirmation emails are sent successfully and I think Paypal data is also getting captured via IPN (or by PDT) as I am getting "Payment Information" filled with data coming from paypal.

Let me know how to get this solved.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is how I have solved it myself !!

[file `\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Payment.php`]

```
public function registerCaptureNotification($amount)
{
    .
    .
    .
    // at the end right before return $this;

    // Custom Code - Send email on Invoice #-
    if (!$this->getIsTransactionPending()){
    if(!$this->getIsFraudDetected()){
    if($invoice)
    {
        @$invoice->sendEmail();
        @$invoice->setEmailSent(true);
    }
    }
    }
    //#-
}
```

However, this will only work with Paypal IPN being called and confirmed...